# async operations in oracle

Tags: oracle, asynchronous, odp.net

Is there anyway one can run async operations in oracle.

> Here is my situation:
>   I have an expensive proc (say it takes 30 mins to run). I have a web-based front-end that controls when this proc to run. I am looking for triggering the running of the proc from the front-end, and not really wait for the proc to complete.i.e., the control should come back to the web application, with a status like say "In progress". 
>   I am specifically looking for a mechanism to get control back to the front-end without waiting for the proc to complete execution.

Thanks in advance,

SK

Answer (score 8):

I'd second OMG Ponies's request for more specifics.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may want to look into the DBMS_JOBS package.  That allows you to submit a job to the database that runs asynchronously.  If you want the database to do something computationally expensive in response to a GUI, for example, your front end could execute something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_asynchronously( p_some_parameter IN PLS_INTEGER, 
                                                p_jobno OUT PLS_INTEGER )
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( p_jobno,
                   'BEGIN ' ||
                      ' some_expensive_procedure( ' || 
                              to_char(p_some_parameter) || ' ); ' ||
                   'END;' );
  RETURN p_jobno;
END;
```

That would submit a background job to run SOME_EXPENSIVE_PROCEDURE, passing in P_SOME_PARAMETER.  The job would not start until the underlying transaction commits which is excellent if SOME_EXPENSIVE_PROCEDURE does something that cannot be rolled back like sending email or FTP-ing a file.

Comment: +1.  Although I'd recommend you look at DBMS_SCHEDULER first.  It's a little more powerful, but it auto-commits jobs so sometimes you still need DBMS_JOB.